# curdled 1/2 & 1/2 in Keurig-type coffee

Tags: food-science, acidity

When I buy coffee (either decaf or regular) at the convenience store and add 1/2 & 1/2, it lasts for several days and several re-heatings without curdling.

BUT when I make Keurig-type coffee using ANY of several different brands I buy at the supermarket, my coffee won't last until the next day and reheating.  It will curdle overnight.

So, does the coffee in the Keurig-type cups just end up having a lot more acid in it from their manufacturing process?

Might it help with my Keurig-type coffee at home if I used the little 1/2 & 1/2 containers that a typical convenience store carries?  I know the chemistry in those little containers is different so that they don't curdle as easily when left out.  (Hence the difference in taste vs regular chilled 1/2 & 1/2).  Maybe they are made with an intentional alkali Ph?

Answer (score 6):

The little 1/2 & 1/2 containers are ultra-pasteurized, so that they can be stable at room temperature.  Ultra-pasteurized milk products will not curdle.  This is why you [cannot make cheese with them](http://www.cheesemaking.com/ultrapasteurizedmilkforcheese.html).

It is also possible that the Keurig coffee, being better roasted and sealed, is more acidic, but it is far more likely the UP milk.  You can test this by finding UP 1/2 & 1/2 at your supermarket in a carton, and comparing.

As a side note, I do find it pretty horrifying that you are making coffee, putting cream in it, and reheating it several days later.  Maybe you could consider making a fresh pot?